# Determining Silverlight Version

Tags: silverlight, devexpress, version

I'm about to start working on some legacy code, specifically a Silverlight component. I need to determine what Silverlight version is used for this component so I don't install unneeded software (specifically DevExpress Silverlight) or have to do any extraneous work.

Comment: That's exactly what I need to find out.

Comment: you don't know what version of devexpress you're going to install?

Comment: I don't know what version of DevExpress the legacy code uses.

Comment: @Yawus: Look at the references in the project as I suggest in the edit of my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Project Version

To find out the version of Silverlight (or other referenced assemblies, such as DevExpress) that your project needs to build, you can look at the project references in the project file.

In the example below, you can see the version stated as part of the `Include` attribute.

```
<Reference Include="System.Windows.Controls, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v4.0\Libraries\Client\System.Windows.Controls.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

### Built Component or App Version

To determine the version of Silverlight (or other referenced assemblies, such as DevExpress) that a specific component is built against, you can use [.NET Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/) or a [similar](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) [reflection](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) tool on the DLL from the XAP file. To get at this DLL, change the XAP extension to ZIP and use your favourite ZIP utility.

### Silverlight Runtime Version

The following javascript enables you to get the version of the installed Silverlight runtime. This is based on the code found at [this blog](http://blog.mdk-photo.com/post/Detecting-Silverlight-version-installed.aspx) (appears to be broken right now). I recall editing it to add some additional browsers and such.

To get the version, use `Silverlight.version`.

```
// Determines the version of the Silverlight runtime.
// Taken from http://blog.mdk-photo.com/post/Detecting-Silverlight-version-installed.aspx

if (!window.Silverlight)
    window.Silverlight = {};

Silverlight.ua = null;

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// detectSilverlightVersion
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function detectSilverlightVersion() {
    var container;
    var silverlightVersion;

    var BinarySearch = function (control, versionNumbers, indx, min, max) {
        if (max < min)
            return -1 // not found

        if (min == max)
            return min
        else {
            versionNumbers[indx] = Math.ceil(min + ((max - min) / 2))
            var isSupported = control.IsVersionSupported(buildVersionString(versionNumbers))
            if (!isSupported)
                return BinarySearch(control, versionNumbers, indx, min, versionNumbers[indx] - 1)
            else
                return BinarySearch(control, versionNumbers, indx, versionNumbers[indx], max)
        }
    }

    var buildVersionString = function (versionNumbers) {
        var versionString = "";
        for (var l = 0; l < versionNumbers.length; ++l) {
            versionString += versionNumbers[l];
            if (l != versionNumbers.length - 1)
                versionString += ".";
        }
        return versionString;
    }

    try {
        var control = null;

        if (Silverlight.ua != null && Silverlight.ua.Browser == 'MSIE') {
            control = new ActiveXObject('AgControl.AgControl');
        }
        else {
            if (navigator.plugins["Silverlight Plug-In"]) {
                container = document.createElement("div")
                document.body.appendChild(container);
                container.innerHTML = '<embed type="application/x-silverlight" />';
                control = container.childNodes[0];
            }
        }

        if (control.Settings) {
            try {
                silverlightVersion = control.Settings.version;
            }
            catch (z) {
            }
        }

        if (!silverlightVersion) {
            var major = 0;
            var minor = 0;
            var revision = 0;
            var build = 0;

            var buildVersionString = function (versionNumbers) {
                var versionString = "";
                for (var l = 0; l < versionNumbers.length; ++l) {
                    versionString += versionNumbers[l];
                    if (l != versionNumbers.length - 1)
                        versionString += ".";
                }
                return versionString;
            }

            var versionNumbers = [0, 0, 0, 0];

            if (arguments[0]) {
                for (var i = 0; i < versionNumbers.length; ++i) {
                    for (var incrementor = 0; incrementor < 100000; ++incrementor) {
                        versionNumbers[i] = incrementor;

                        if (!control.IsVersionSupported(buildVersionString(versionNumbers))) {
                            versionNumbers[i] = incrementor - 1;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                versionNumbers[0] = BinarySearch(control, versionNumbers, 0, 0, 20);
                versionNumbers[1] = BinarySearch(control, versionNumbers, 1, 0, 20);
                versionNumbers[2] = BinarySearch(control, versionNumbers, 2, 0, 100000);
                versionNumbers[3] = BinarySearch(control, versionNumbers, 3, 0, 20);
            }
            silverlightVersion = buildVersionString(versionNumbers);
        }

        control = null;
    }
    catch (e) {

    }

    if (container) {
        container.parentNode.removeChild(container);
    }

    if (!silverlightVersion)
        silverlightVersion = "Not installed!";

    return silverlightVersion;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// detectUserAgent Parses UA string and stores relevant data in Silverlight.ua.
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Silverlight.detectUserAgent = function () {
    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;

    Silverlight.ua = { OS: 'Unsupported', Browser: 'Unsupported' };

    //Silverlight does not support pre-Windows NT platforms
    if (ua.indexOf('Windows NT') >= 0) {
        Silverlight.ua.OS = 'Windows';
    }
    else if (ua.indexOf('PPC Mac OS X') >= 0) {
        Silverlight.ua.OS = 'MacPPC';
    }
    else if (ua.indexOf('Intel Mac OS X') >= 0) {
        Silverlight.ua.OS = 'MacIntel';
    }

    if (Silverlight.ua.OS != 'Unsupported') {
        if (ua.indexOf('MSIE') >= 0) {
            if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Win64') == -1) {
                if (parseInt(ua.split('MSIE')[1]) >= 6) {
                    Silverlight.ua.Browser = 'MSIE';
                }

            }
        }
        else if (ua.indexOf('Firefox') >= 0) {
            var version = ua.split('Firefox/')[1].split('.');
            var major = parseInt(version[0]);
            if (major >= 2) {
                Silverlight.ua.Browser = 'Firefox';
            }
            else {
                var minor = parseInt(version[1]);
                if ((major == 1) && (minor >= 5)) {
                    Silverlight.ua.Browser = 'Firefox';
                }
            }
        }

        else if (ua.indexOf('Chrome') >= 0) {
            Silverlight.ua.Browser = 'Chrome';
        }

        else if (ua.indexOf('Safari') >= 0) {
            Silverlight.ua.Browser = 'Safari';
        }

        else if (ua.indexOf('Opera') >= 0) {
            Silverlight.ua.Browser = 'Opera';
        }
    }
}

// Detect the user agent at script load time
Silverlight.detectUserAgent();

$(this).ready(function () {
    Silverlight.version = detectSilverlightVersion();
});
```

Comment: I wasn't looking specific code to execute, but rather some sort of properties view that I could use to find the specific Silverlight version.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The specific version of what, exactly?  See the Component Version information for getting the version of a Silverlight app or control. The solution file will contain the versions of Silverlight references.

Answer (score 0):

One approach might to open one of your project files (.csproj / .vbproj) and find the TargetFrameworkIdentifier.

A project targeting Silverlight 4:

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>`
```

A project targeting Silverlight 5:

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v5.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```